# Distance of projection on a curve

Tags: geometry

Suppose there is a circle. Maybe, to be able to plot it in wxMaxima or Octave, $f=\sqrt{1-t^2}$. Then there's a second circle (or half-circle), $g=k\sqrt{1-(\frac{t}{k})^2}$, $k>1$ (e.g. 1.2). Now suppose these traces are made up of sampled (discrete) points, both traces same points. They should look something like this (f - blue, g - red):

[image: graph]

The problem: how to calculate $g-f$ alongside the Y axis *only*? Note that the first blue point actually falls between the 2nd and 3rd reds. Linear interpolation is fine, the samples can be more than can be seen here and it doesn't need to be ultra-precise. Also, the $f$ function can be more exotic, but clearly defined and the method of determination should apply to any curve (as long as the tangent doesn't go astray, I suppose, which it doesn't in my case).

My attempt at reasoning was based on this drawing (sorry for the lengthy explanation, I'd rather make sure I say everything):

[image: logic]

The $f$ (blue) point is in $O(0,0)$, the two $g$ (red) points are $A(x_1,y_1)$ and $B(x_2,y_2)$. Another point, $M(x_2,y_1)$, can be added to form the triangle $AMO$, where $PQ$ is the intersection of the projection of $O$ onto $AB$. This means that the length of the projection is $PQ+QO$. $QO$ has coordinates $(0,y_1)$ and:

$\frac{PQ}{BM} = \frac{AQ}{AM} =>$

$PQ = \frac{BM}{AM}AQ$

and with

$BM = y_2-y_1$

$AQ = x_1$

$AM = x_2-x_1 =>$

$PQ = \frac{y_2-y_1}{x_2-x_1} x_1 + y_1$

or, in a more general form:

$PQ = \frac{y_{n+1}-y_n}{x_{n+1}-x_n} x_n + y_n$

The two vectors are in two column matrices. Next comes a `for n:1 thru length(f)` loop where I first take care that $g[x_{n+1},1]-f[x_n,1]>=0$, to avoid the problem where $f[1,1]=(-1,0)$ falls between $g[2,1]$ and $g[3,1]$ (currently the maximum offset on X axis is only one point, it may differ given other sampling rates). If false, it's:

$PQ = \frac{y_{n+2}-y_{n+1}}{x_{n+2}-x_{n+1}} x_{n} + y_{n}$

In the end I do a $g-PQ$ to find the length of the projection.

Is what I'm doing valid enough? I doubt it because the results I'm getting are... well, not as expected (a growing siney-wave). It looks like this should be basic math but it's like reaching for the stars tright now... so I kindly ask for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's correct. For a given point $g(x)$, find the bracketing abscissas where $f$ is available, let $f(x_0),f(x_1)$ and get the vertical distance after linear interpolation

$$d=\left|\frac{f(x_0)(x_1-x)+f(x_1)(x-x_0)}{x_1-x_0} - g(x)\right|.$$

Comment: Thank you for the answer, but if what I did was correct, then why do I get strange results? I am not near my files now, but I'll return tomorrow and post a more relevant graph. Come to think of it, there may be another question brewing.

Comment: Make sure that $x_0\le x\le x_1$.

Comment: The result was similar to x*sin(x), ugly. I did a check with the <code>for</code> loop, but you are right, because I was only checking at the beginning, where I need to increment by 1 (x=x+1, checked); then comes the middle part, where x=x (checked), but then, towards the end, I have to decrement by 1 -- this, I forgot. Which means the implementation was wrong. I can't vote up but I marked this as the answer, thank you.